# How count rounds in a circle?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, geolocation, oracle-apex

I've asked a similar question before but this is different. I am using Oracle APEX 22.2 to develop a PWA app which should work on Android phones. It's a game for kids. The code used is pure JavaScript. The game is like a race in a circle. There's a circular place. The race starts with the kid standing on a point of a 10 meters horizontal line which represents the starting line of the race. The kid has it's phone on him with Location service switched on. The race starts when each kid clicks the "Start Race" button. Then The kid starts running. When the kid reaches the starting line again on any point of the 10 meters wide, it means they passed one round. The app then should assign the round number to the dedicated item round_no each time the kid passes the starting line from any point of the 10 meters wide line.
My solution uses the Geo-location API to specify the starting longitude. Then, if the longitude value increase, then decreases then increases again, that means the kid passes one round, because when kid starts running forward, this will cause longitude to increase. Then when they pass the half of the circle, the longitude will decrease. Then when increasing again after getting decreased, this means it passes the whole circle.
But there is a case where a kid could drop something exactly before the starting position. In that case, it will pass the starting position, then go back behind the starting position, then pass it again. In this case, the code will count it as if it were a round when it's not.
I'd appreciate if there's any better solution to know if the kid has passed a whole cycle.
Below, is the code I am using...

```js
var lo, la, slo, sla, roundNoVal;
function getCurrentLoc() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    slo = position.coords.longitude;
    sla = position.coords.latitude;
  });
}

function watchPosition() {
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
    lo = position.coords.longitude;
    if (lo > slo && g == "" && l == "") {
      g = 1;
    } else if (g !== "" && l == "" && lo < slo) {
      l = 1;
    } else if (g !== "" && l !== "" && lo > slo) {
      g = "";
      l = "";
      roundNoVal = document.getElementById("P6_ROUND_NO").innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("P6_ROUND_NO").innerHTML = roundNoVal + 1;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<body onload="getCurrentLoc()">
  <input id="P6_ROUND_NO">
<button onclick="watchPosition()">Start Race</botton>
</body>
```